# Python: How to block user from calling module via another module(by attributing it)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, python-3.9

I have a python library `os` in my module. However, I do not want a user to call `os`, like that: `my_module.os`. I need this restriction for `exec()` to allow users to use only specified modules. Maybe It can be done with `AST`.
How to inspect code properly to find similar situations? Or It is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `my_module` a python package with the following structure.

```
my_module/
|-- __init__.py
|-- my_module.py
```

For example `my_module.py` has following structure.

```
import os

def function_one():
.
.
.


def function_two():
.
.
.
```

Now inside `__init__.py`

```
from my_module import function_one, function_two
```

Now, when you import `my_module` in a `example.py` you will be able to only use `function_one` and `function_two`.

example.py file:

```
import my_module

my_module.function_one()    #runs without issues

my_module.os    #throws attribute error
```